# SQL Select Max within a Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I've been having trouble with a SQL subquery, and although I imagine this is fairly basic, the internet does not seem to hold the answer. I have a subquery inside a FROM statement which has a `MAX()` function within it, and I cannot seem to reference this data in the rest of the query. The query is here:

```
SELECT 
    m.nameFirst, m.nameLast, t.salary, te.name
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MAX(salary), teamID 
     FROM 
         salaries 
     GROUP BY 
         teamID) AS t, master AS m, teams AS te, salaries AS s
WHERE 
    t.salary = s.salary 
    AND s.teamID = t.teamID 
    AND s.playerID = m.playerID 
    AND te.teamID = t.teamID;
```

The subquery, when run by itself, returns results which look like this:

```
+-------------+--------+
| MAX(salary) | teamID |
+-------------+--------+
|    13166667 | ANA    |
|    16000000 | ARI    |...
```

However, when I try to run the whole query, I get the following result:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.salary' in 'field list'

I have tried a few different things, such as `t.MAX(salary)`, `MAX(t.salary)`, and even just `t.*`, but as I need to use the subquery's results later, it just throws different errors.

What name should I use to call the results of the MAX column of the subquery?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. Please which one you are really use?

Comment: This is because there is no salary returned in subquery likewise the error name it as `max(salary) as some_name ` then `t.some_name=s.salary`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an alias for max column and your code will work :

```
SELECT m.nameFirst, m.nameLast, t.salary, te.name
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(salary) as salary, teamID 
    FROM salaries 
    GROUP BY teamID
) AS t, master AS m, teams AS te, salaries AS s
WHERE t.salary=s.salary AND s.teamID=t.teamID AND s.playerID = m.playerID AND te.teamID=t.teamID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give it an alias to make it easier or in this case accessible

eg

```
  SELECT MAX(salary) as max_salary, teamID ...
```

then later simply reference

```
  t.max_salary
```

so in your example change it like this

```
SELECT m.nameFirst, m.nameLast, t.max_salary, te.name
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(salary) as max_salary, teamID 
 -- rest of query
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no salary returned in subquery likewise the error name it as `max(salary) as some_name` then `t.some_name=s.salary`